# Meaning of "Flash runs out of browsers, not limited to operating systems and browsers"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

From [a web-page](https://blog.360totalsecurity.com/en/2018-flash-exploit-360-intercepts-vulnerability/):

> Flash runs out of browsers, **not limited to operating systems and browsers.** Consequently, attackers prefer to use Flash vulnerability as a weapon. Adobe has announced to stop updating and offering technical support for Flash in 2020 due to its weakness in security.

What is the meaning of "not limited to operating systems and browsers"? Why do the authors repeat the word **browsers** and use the preposition **to**?

As I understand, Flash indeed usually starts running when you visit a webpage that has some Flash animation embedded in it. You visit the page using a browser - hence "Flash runs out of browsers".

But what is "not limited **to** operating systems and browsers"? It can run in an operating system, or in a browser, or in *something else*?

Comment: More context needed.

Comment: consider one of the computer forums - like computer science.

Comment: Heaven only knows. The writer is very obviously not a native English speaker and doesn’t exactly show great mastery of either the language nor writing in general. The sentence in question is basically meaningless. It’s probably an error that was missed in any (clearly limited) proofreading the author may have done before publishing the text.

Comment: @Hot Licks: The context is pretty obviously "writer is a non-native speaker", which implies there's little to be gained by knowing anything else about the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Flash runs out of browsers, not limited to operating systems and
>   browsers.

Wow, that is some poor writing.

From the rest of the paragraph, I’m going to guess the writer is trying to say that Flash, and its vulnerabilities, appears in almost identical form in different browsers and different operating systems -- but that is meeting the author more than halfway.

He also might be trying to say that Flash can run directly, without a browser (“out” of a browser), but really, that is not relevant.

Never write like this.

Comment: Given that [The most popular third-party browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Opera **no longer support Flash** on iOS devices, due to the **decreasing popularity of the format**,](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/ipad/how-get-flash-on-iphone-ipad-2017-3460979/) I suggest the first clause means *There will soon be no browsers left that still support Flash,* rather than *Flash runs within browsers (as opposed to within operating systems)*. But you're essentially quite right; it's just garbage text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- yes, "run out" could mean "exhaust one's supply". God knows.  I hope this passage was the product of drugs or alcohol, because I would hate to think someone writes like this sober.